# Get ActiveRecord::Base kind object from another same kind object based on the same table record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ftom the slide 139 of the presentation [SOLID Ruby, SOLID Rails](http://www.slideshare.net/jcfischer/solid-ruby-solid-rails)

If have defined 2 classes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
  table_name = "users"
  ...
end
```

Then I got `r = Registration.find(39)`

How can I get the corresponding object `u` of type `User` from the object `r` where `u.id == r.id` with no database query?

Comment: If they're both using the users table then surely u would be r?  You'd be fetching the same object from the db

Comment: The User model contains a different from Registration method set

Comment: In short I don't think this'll be possible in rails to pass from one model to another without a DB query.  Having 2 models accessing the same db with different methods in each is also ridiculous to me.  You should restructure your site.

Comment: By that I mean 2 models with different methods accessing the same db table without using single table inheritance

Comment: why are you using the same table for diferent class?
Registration is a SuperClass from User?

Comment: That idea of incapsulating different model aspects into different models (as opposed to modules) was briefly mentioned in the presenation I referenced to in my question. Thinking of it I can't get how to cast one model object into another model object without database being bothered.